# Minimization of a very simple polynomial

Tags: polynomials, mathematical-optimization

**1.** I get a very strange output for this minimization

```
Minimize[(1 - x y)^2 + x^2, {x, y}]
(*{0, {x -> Indeterminate, y -> Indeterminate}}*)
```

Is it correct? Can you help me to interpret it. I would expect that the image of a polynomial with real coefficients should be closed implying a well defined solution of the above expression.

**2.** Notice how different the output is from

```
Minimize[x^2 + y^2, {x, y}]
{0, {x -> 0, y -> 0}}
```

**3.** But let us look now at a more broad class of functions

```
Minimize[1/x^2, {x}]
(*Minimize::natt: The minimum is not attained at any point satisfying the given constraints.*)
(*{0, {x -> -\[Infinity]}}*)
```

In contrast to 1., the warning is given (per comment of Michael E2 the same warning is given in 1. with a newer version of MA).

What should be the correct output in the cases **1.** and **3.**?

---

After reading some comments below, I re-read the documentation

- `Minimize` is also known as infimum.
- `Minimize` finds the global minimum of $f$ subject to the constraints given.

It seems MA makes not distinction between the minimum and the infimum, which is fine with me. However, there is one and interested readers can find more under [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342749/what-is-the-difference-between-minimum-and-infimum).

Comment: I get `Minimize::natt` in # **1** in V12.3.1.  It has no minimum in $\bf R^2$.  It's a bit odd that it says there's no answer and then gives one. That it is the greatest lower bound kind of makes sense.  (The function approaches zero from above as $x \rightarrow 0$, $y \rightarrow \pm\infty$ along $xy=1$.)

Comment: It strikes me as a better result than alternatives such as returning unevaluated.

Comment: @DanielLichtblay: Disagreed: the output `{0, {x -> Indeterminate, y -> Indeterminate}}` is informative (see Minimize/Scope/Multivariate Problems and an example `Minimize[{x^2 + 1, x y >= 1}, {x, y}]` there), whereas the returned input isn't.

Comment: @user64494 We are saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The primary difference between case #1 and case #3 is that the former is a polynomial, whereas the latter is not.

As per Mathematica documentation for `Minimize`, if the function to be minimzed and the constraints (if any) for minimization happen to be polynomials, then `Minimize` would give us the global minimum (if one exists in the first place, that is). A quick 3D plot for 1 reveals that it has no global minimum, which explains why `Minimize` demonstrates the behaviour it does.

[image: Plot for #1, both x and y run from -1000 to 1000]

In fact, #1 describes a saddle surface.

In case of #3, however, it can be clearly understood that the function descends from $\infty$ as `Abs[x]` grows larger, on either side of the $y$-axis, and as `Abs[x]` $ \rightarrow \infty $ on either side, `y` $ \rightarrow 0 $ asymptotically. There's no global minimum again, in-fact, no stationary points at all (contrast this with saddle/inflection points of a curve, where the univariate function is stationary, even if it's not an extremum).

So, in both cases, the output obtained is what one should expect, going by the behaviour of the function, and the Mathematica documentation for `Minimize`.

**Edit 1:**

Since the limits for my 3D plot were $x \in [-1000,1000], y \in [-1000,1000]$, the origin is a suitable point to check if there's a saddle point there or not. From the looks of the plot, there should be one.

Condition for a function $f(x,y)$ to have saddle point at a given point $(a,b)$: $f_{xx}f_{yy} < f_{xy}^2$ at $(a,b)$.

Now, we have the following:

```
f=(1 - x y)^2 + x^2;

D[f, x, y]^2 /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}
```

gives 4, and,

```
D[f, x, x] D[f, y, y] /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}
```

gives 0, thus demonstrating that $(0,0,1)$ is indeed a saddle point for case #1.

**Edit 2**

~ From the comments to my answer, I realised that I had misinterpreted the question. The following is my attempt to answer it after getting the confusion clarified. Thanks to @user64494 and @yarchik for their useful comments.~

As it turns out, `Minimize` has no issues with saddle points whatsoever, at least not so in case of #1.

The fundamental issue seems to be about the domains that `Minimize` accepts. Among others, it accepts `Reals` and `Integers`. But NOT `Complexes`.

That `Minimize` has no issue with $(0,0)$ being a saddle point can be ascertained via the following:

```
In[1]:= f = (1 - x y)^2 + x^2;
Minimize[{f, {x, y} \[Element] Integers}, {x, y}]

Out[1]= {1, {x -> 0, y -> 0}}
```

which is precisely what one should expect.

As per the following condition: "If the minimum is achieved only infinitesimally outside the region defined by the constraints, or only asymptotically, `Minimize` will return the infimum and the closest specifiable point", when restricted to `Reals` (which is the default domain for variables `x` and `y`), `Minimize` tries to figure out the value at which the infimum $0$ occurs. A minimum is attainable, an infimum not necessarily so, and when it's not, the best one can speak about is "tending towards the infimum". A quick use of `Solve` would show that the values of `x` and `y` at which the function evaluates to $0$ are typically complex - but `Minimize` cannot deal with variables in the domain `Complexes`. As such, despite providing the correct infimum value, it fails to show the corresponding values for the variables.

The reason that this confusion arises only when the domain is `Reals` instead of `Integers` is because of the word *infinitesimally* in the documentation. As you can see, the minimum in case of `Integers` is $1$, while for `Reals` this "minimum" is $0$ - this difference is not infintesimal.

Comment: If $x\to 0$ and $y= \frac 1 x \to \infty$. then $(1 - x y)^2 + x^2 \to 0$. This explains the result of `Minimize`.

Comment: @yarchik: `0` is the infimum of the polynomial under consideration and this infimum is not attained at any point. This is described in [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html)

Comment: @user64494 I am not sure I found the same place in the documentation as you did. But I read "If the minimum is achieved only infinitesimally outside the region defined by the constraints, or only asymptotically, Minimize will return the infimum and the closest specifiable point." So where is the closest specifiable point?

Comment: @yarchik See Minimize/Scope/Multivariate Problems: and  an example  `Minimize[{x^2 + 1, x y >= 1}, {x, y}]` there.

Comment: @user64494 Ok, thank you for pointing out, its well hidden. So it is not a bug, but a feature.

Comment: @yarchik Please check the Edit 2 section in my answer.

Comment: @user64494 "If $x \rightarrow 0$ and $y=\frac{1}{x}$..." - what warrants such a relation between the variables? This explanation works for the multivariate eg in documentation because of the constraint condition, but in the current case, the actual relation is $y=\frac{1}{x} \pm i$. I am a bit confused as to how to relate the explanation for the example context to this one. Should it not rather be along lines of domain consideration?

Comment: @abstract: Could you ground $y=\frac{1}{x} \pm i$? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 just setting $f(x,y)=0$ for #1 case. Making $y$ subject of formula, and assuming for this calculation that these variables can take complex values. The equation gets factorised into two parts - $(1-x y) + i x$  and $(1-x y) - i x$.